# JasperStarter Parametros Array e Collection

Tags: php, cmd, jasper

Estou trabalhando com relatórios Jasper no PHP.
Está tudo certo, consigo listar os mesmos sem problema, mas quando possui um parâmetro Array ou Collection ocorre erro.
Tentei passar via CMD de varias formas o parâmetro Collection, exemplo:

parametro = 1
parametro = (1,2)
parametro = {1,2}

Não sei mais oque tentar ;/

Answer (score 0):

descobri que o Jasperstarter aceita apenas parâmetros string e date, sendo assim para que meu filtro funcionasse, mudei ele para String para que eu pudesse passar como o parâmetro o Próprio Where.
Resumindo, monto o  Where no código e passo como parâmetro, vlw